# Two Eclipse running on two different system will share same workbench

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two system, one in my office and one in my home. I am working on one Java application. I am facing one problem which is, after completing work in office I need to do it at home. For this before closing the eclipse, I copy the complete project in pendrive then I copy it into my home system, and then able to work from home and able to start from the place where I left the program in office. Same task I need to do, now from home to office.
Is there any eclipse plug-in or any other way available by which I will able to synchronize both the workbench.

There are some plug-in avilable like **SVN, CVS** but these plugin require one server, static IP address etc which is costly.

Example:- **Google Drive**

if you install google drive on two different system with same google account and if you do any change in one system then this change will reflect on other system also.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:If you are using a personal computer at work or if the office computer allows it, you can use Dropbox.Create the project in Dropbox and then when at work,all you need to do is import the project (do not copy into workspace).What ever changes you make is persisted in Dropbox.

Comment: thanx ... but from my knowledge ...dropbox is also not free...
(free for a year after that some charge is there...)

Comment: It is free.You only pay if you want to extend the services(like getting more space)

Comment: Don't store the entire workspace in Dropbox. The .metadata directory can contain information specific to that machine. If you must do this using Dropbox or another cloud sync, do it at the project level.

Comment: That is absolutely right.I think I made a mistake in my answer.editing now

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is a version control system, and one that is available as a free service. This allows you to store the code on an external server and have it reachable both from work and home.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) is very popular these days for good reasons. It has a good Eclipse plugin, Egit, that comes preinstalled in later Eclipse releases. There are several external repositories that you can use, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378120/is-there-a-free-private-git-repository), or just Google. Many offer free hosting for small projects.

This will require a bit of a learning curve, but it will help you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I use a small (pocket size) external drive. I have eclipse and my workspace on it (and other tools I need) - I can easily plug it into my work or home PC (or client PC if traveling). It works great - just assign it the same drive letter on both home and work PC.

I would also recommend you use a code repository in addition to an external drive to store the source code - CVS, SVN, Git, etc.